# Convert it from DB into YAML in Rails

Tags: ruby

```
rake db:fixtures:load
```

The YAML file which I put in the test/fixtures following is imported automatically by DB.
Is there a method that converts the contents of the database into a YAML file for fixtures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a great plugin called [yaml_db](http://github.com/adamwiggins/yaml_db/tree/master).
I used it a couple of time to migrate data from one database to an other.

Comment: I haven't tested it with Rails 2.0.x but only with Rails >= 2.1.x. However it should work with 2.0.x as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on my mac so I can't try it, but can't you use to_yaml?